# Trying to build customer login in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, authentication

I am trying to debug a customer login framework in Python.  Some users have existing accounts and for them, I want the program to continue on.  That portion works.  For those without accounts, I want to create an account for them (just their first and last name), add it to existing accounts, and then allow them to login using the newly created account.  Two tries to correctly login not case sensitive using any account and then the program quits.  I think I have the framework there, but for some reason my except: statement is not working.

```
def login():
    useraccounts = ['bob doe', 'joe doe', 'jane doe']
    user = input('Please log in using your first and last name\n')
    user = user.lower()
    try:
        for user in useraccounts:
            print('Welcome,',login,'.\n')
            break
    except:
        print('No user found. Please create a new account.')
        newacct = input('Please enter your first and last name. This will be your login information.')
        newacct = newacct.lower()
        useraccounts.append(newacct)
        print('Welcome,',newacct,'. Please log in using your new account.\n')

login()
```

Comment: this makes no sense.... you are not logging them in ... at all ... and this will just print "welcome <user>" for all useraccounts ... do you just want login to return a name? or what? loggin typically indicates you save the state of the saved user...

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this might work ... but your problem statement is severly lacking at the moment

```
def login(useraccounts = ['bob doe', 'joe doe', 'jane doe']):
    username = input("Enter your username?")
    if username not in useraccounts:
       if input("User Not found Would you like to register?").lower()[0] == "y":
          useraccounts.append(username)
          print("Registered! now login!")
       return login()
    # else your username is in your list of user accounts
    print(f"Hi {username}")
```

as seen below

```
>>> login()
Enter your username?joran
User Not found Would you like to register?y
Registered! now login!
Enter your username?joran
Hi joran
>>>
```